# Is it possible to restrict access to Chrome extension using free Google Apps subscription?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm using free Google Apps subscription and I've published self-made extension in Chrome Store. Also, I need to restrict access to that extension to only my domain users.

I tried to follow [Google manual](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2663860), but I couldn't get access to 'Device management > Chrome management' (got an unexpected redirect from 'Device management' page to Apps list while clicking on 'Chrome management' link) and there was no option 'everyone at mydomain.com' into extension 'Visibility section' — only 'trusted testers'.

So, maybe it's because of my free subscription or it's Google Apps issue or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, That feature (and process) is only available for [Google Apps for work and Education accounts](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6177431?hl=en).

However, you can try to restrict access to your chrome extension (using your free account) before publishing it to public by [publishing it to test accounts](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#publishing-to-test-accounts).

> **Publishing to test accounts**
>
> When you publish to test accounts, your app’s store listing only appears to you and any users who are logged into these test accounts that you specify. Your app won’t appear in search results, so you’ll need to give testers a direct link to your app’s listing. Testing also gives you a chance to see how the license server integrateswith your app if you plan to charge your it using Chrome Web Store Payments.
>
> To edit your list of accounts, click Edit your tester accounts. You can enter single accounts, or create a Google Group so that this set of users can test your app. See the section below to learn how to set up Group Publishing.
>
> Once you’re ready to publish, click Publish to test accounts.
>
> You’ll need to unpublish the app if you want to publish to the world later.